# Extending to a probability measure from a CDF

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

For any real random variable $X$ it is sufficient to describe the cumulative distribution function to give the entire distribution. Why is that?

In other words, if we assign numbers on the collection of sets of the form $(-\infty, x]$ such that the assignment meets the conditions of the CDF (non-decreasing, right continuity, $F(-\infty)=0,F(+\infty)=1$)  then we can extend this assignment to all the Borel sets. How is that accomplished exactly?

I thought [Cartheodory's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem) would be used here, but the statement of the theorem requires a ring of sets which $(-\infty, x]$ is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked two different questions.

---

The first question was: *For any real random variable $X$ it is sufficient to describe the cumulative distribution function to give the entire distribution. Why is that?*

Two probability measures $P$ and $Q$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ that coincide on a generator of $\mathcal{B}$ that is closed to finite intersections, are identical (this is due to [Dynkin's $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system#Dynkin%27s_%CF%80-%CE%BB_theorem)). The set $\big\{(-\infty,x] : x \in \mathbb{R}\big\}$ is such a generator.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with cdfs $F_X$ and $F_Y$, and with probability distributions $P_X$ and $P_Y$, respectively. If $F_X = F_Y$, then $P_X\big((-\infty,x]\big) = F_X(x) = F_Y(x) = P_Y\big((-\infty,x]\big)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, hence, $P_X = P_Y$, which is to say $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution.

---

As for your second question: *if we assign numbers on the collection of sets of the form $(-\infty, x]$ such that the assignment meets the conditions of the CDF (non-decreasing, right continuity, $F(-\infty)=0,F(+\infty)=1$)  then we can extend this assignment to all the Borel sets. How is that accomplished exactly?*

It can be shown that if $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow[0,1]$ satisfies the axioms of a CDF, and we define $X:(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ to be the inverse of $F$ (more precisely $F$'s [quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function), which reduces to $F$'s inverse if $F$ is invertible) , then $F_X = F$, when $X$ is considered as a random variable over the probability space $\big((0,1), \mathcal{B}_{(0,1)}, \lambda\big|_{(0,1)}\big)$, $\lambda$ being the Lebesgue measure on the real line. $X$'s distribution $P_X$ is an extension of $F_X$ to all Borel sets.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the second part more please? How do we now get a measure on a real borel set?

Comment: @Shahab: Every real random variable $X$ over a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ determines a probability measure $P_X$ on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ as follows: $P_X(B) = P\big(X\in B\big)$.

Comment: But your induced probability measure on B(0,1) is the lebesgue measure & independent of F. This is the point which is not clear to me

Comment: @Shahab: Take, for instance, $F(x) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\arctan(x)}{\pi}$. Check that $F$ satisfies the axioms of a CDF (graph it, it will help), and that it is invertible with inverse $F^{-1}(y) = \tan\big(\pi(y-\frac{1}{2})\big)$ on the domain $(0,1)$. Now define $X$ to be this inverse, and consider $X$ to be a random variable on the probability space $\big((0,1),\mathcal{B}_{(0,1)},\lambda\big|_{(0,1)}\big)$. Denote $X$'s cdf by $F_X$. Then for every $y \in \mathbb{R}$, $F_X(y) = \lambda\big(F^{-1}\leq y\big) = \lambda\big(\{x \in (0,1) : x \leq F(y)\}\big) = F(y)$. So $F_X = F$.

Comment: It is not clear to me why $\lambda(\{x\in(0,1):x\le F(y)\})=F(y)$.

Comment: Also if possible can you give me a reference for the second part?

Comment: @Shahab: Let $c$ be any number in the interval $(0,1)$. Then $\big\{x \in (0,1) : x \leq c\big\} = (0,c]$, and $\lambda\big((0,c]\big) = c$, right? Putting it together, you get $\lambda\big(\big\{x \in (0,1) : x \leq c\big\}\big) = c$. Now substitute $F(y)$ for $c$ to get $\lambda\big(\big\{x \in (0,1) : x \leq F(y)\big\}\big) = F(y)$.

Comment: @Shahab: As for reference, you can take [the Wikipedia article on Quantile Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function). All you need is the following facts specified in the "Definition" section: that the quantile $Q$ is a real-valued function with domain $(0,1)$ satisfying for every $p \in (0,1)$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ that $Q(p) \leq x$ iff $p \leq F(x)$. A more explicit treatment is given in the [German version of the same Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verallgemeinerte_inverse_Verteilungsfunktion) in the sections "Definition" and "Eigenschaften".